# Flutter gradle error after using shared preferences version 2.1.0 on Android env

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

I have a problem after using Shared Preferences version 2.1.0 on Android env (emulator).
The problem is stated like this (thank you very much if you are willing to answer my question) :

---

```
What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':shared_preferences_android'.
> Could not load compiled classes for build file 'C:\Users\rakhtama\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\shared_preferences_android-2.1.0\android\build.gradle' from cache.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':shared_preferences_android' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':shared_preferences_android' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

---

And this is files related to the error :

---

C:\Users\rakhtama\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\shared_preferences_android-2.1.0\android\build.gradle :

```
group 'io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
    }
}

rootProject.allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

allprojects {
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable 'AndroidGradlePluginVersion', 'InvalidPackage', 'GradleDependency'
        baseline file("lint-baseline.xml")
    }
    dependencies {
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
        testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:5.0.0'
    }


    testOptions {
        unitTests.includeAndroidResources = true
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
        unitTests.all {
            testLogging {
               events "passed", "skipped", "failed", "standardOut", "standardError"
               outputs.upToDateWhen {false}
               showStandardStreams = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

{project-folder}\android\gradle\wrapper\gradler-wrapper.properties
[image]

---

{project-folder}\android\build.gradle :
[image]

---

{project-folder}\android\gradle.properties :
[image]

---

pubspec.yaml :
[image]

---

Thank you very much if you are willing to answer my question.

I have tried to run "flutter clean" & ".\gradlew clean build" but the error stil exist.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the below step, it will be resolved,

1. RUN `flutter clean` in the terminal
2. Pug get from pubspec.yamal